# Send "Invisible" Message using C# to GSM modem

Tags: sms, messaging, status, sendmessage, gsmcomm

How can I send an “invisible” SMS via a GSM modem using the C# (the recipient won’t see it, but I will know the status of receipt) to find out if the phone is on or not - “Ping-SMS”

Answer (score 0):

You must set PS_MESSAGE_CLASS0 value as CLASS parameter provided in a call to SmsSendMessage.